# Does every denomination / sect have a catechism?

Tags: denomination-survey, tradition, creeds-and-confessions, catechism

In Lutheranism, there's the *[Small Catechism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther%27s_Small_Catechism), [Large Catechism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther%27s_Large_Catechism),* and the [*Book of Concord*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Concord), with each book in series getting much larger and having more specific doctrinal material.  Even though the practicing theology of Lutherans spans crazy extremes, even the pastor who may be pushing the envelope against traditional doctrines is nonetheless apt to teach the *Small Catechism* to his or her students with pride.

Does every major faith tradition in Christianity ultimately have a catechism?

Comment: Catechisms are generally summaries of confessions of faith/doctine. Also they are generally old - usually several hundred years (there are, of course, exceptions). More recent denominations are less likely to have them, and some denominations simply have a confession of faith/doctrine

Comment: Maybe consider changing your question to "Which denominations have a Catechism".  I suggest because you used the word "every" and I promise that if someone says, "yes" there will be someone else who says, "but you forgot <x>"

Comment: However, that would make your question a polling question and will be closed.

Comment: @DanAndrews There is no sense in making this a list question. As you not that would not be acceptable, but in it's current form it already isn't a list question. It's a bit either basic or rhetorical perhaps but any decent expert to come along will be able to give a perhaps useful overview of what sort of churches do and don't use catechisms. The issue with the wording of "every" is a bit pedantic. I don't see any purpose in closing this on a technicality when there is obviously and answerable question surrounding this issue that somebody interested in the subject could expound on.

Comment: @Caleb, this will be come a conversation question.  And even if an "expert" were to answer this question laying out each denomination that has a Catechism, there will be another that will say that there is one that does not.  I propose that someone (as Affable Geek has) post an example of a denomination that does not.  However even there, another "expert" has suggested that it does in fact have one.  This isn't a good fit for StackExchange as there is not one correct answer.

Comment: @DanAndrews I don't see it, but you are free to VTC yourself. To my mind this has a correct and useful potential answer: "No" with some examples of ones that don't and their the major reasons why not and maybe some background on how they come into use in general.

Comment: I can't VTC yet, that's why I flagged it.  Maybe if I quit getting all of those downvotes from you <jk>

Answer (score 2):

No most pentecostals do not have a catechism. Some churches do have introduction to the faith classes but there are no predefined standards.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but it can be argued that each denomination has a doctrinal belief.  Though there may be smaller denominations that have not officially organized nor written a catechism/doctrinal belief system, it makes sense that the beliefs in common of people taking part of the community actually do subscribe to a "doctrine."

Wikipedia's definition of doctrine offers a hint to this thinking:

> Often doctrine specifically connotes a corpus of religious dogma as it is promulgated by a church, but not necessarily: doctrine is also used to refer to a principle of law, in the common law traditions, established through a history of past decisions, such as the doctrine of self-defense, or the principle of fair use, or the more narrowly applicable first-sale doctrine. In some organizations, doctrine is simply defined as "that which is taught", in other words the basis for institutional teaching of its personnel internal ways of doing business. - Wikipedia, "Doctrine"

Catechism points to belief, explaining what is believed. Peter writes that it's important that we have a reason for what we believe:

> "... in your hearts honor Christ the Lord as holy, always being prepared to make a defense to anyone who asks you for a reason for the hope that is in you; yet do it with gentleness and respect" 1 Peter 3:15

Hope this is helpful.