# which denominations have a catechism and if possible can you add a link to it?

Tags: catechism

I'd like to know which denominations have a catechism and be able to review them.

As a bonus has there been any attempt at a global type of common catechism?

Comment: I don't know whether out of 40,000 or so denominations it would be possible to completely research *all* the ones that have catechisms. This is WAY broad.

Comment: Regarding your last question, although there have often been dialogue between different denominations (e.g. Lutherans and Roman Catholics), there isn't any sort of "common Catechism" between denominations. The only text that is recognized globally would be the Bible, and even then, there are disagreements as to what it actually contains (e.g. does it include the Apocrypha).

Comment: Related: [Does every denomination / sect have a catechism?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17085/16688)

Comment: I didn't ask for all. One person doesn't  need the entire answer. How is it wrong to build a list?

Comment: The problem with list questions is that Stack Exchange answers are expected to be (a) either objectively right or objectively not quite right, and therefore (b) independent of each other (ie giving a correct answer in themselves regardless of what other answers say), and therefore (c) complete. And therefore yes, one person needs the entire answer. What if someone gave a critical part of the list and subsequently their answer was deleted for whatever reason?

Comment: So i can ask for 10, or some distinct number of most cited catechism, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

A summary of every catechism and every denomination which subscribes to a catechism would be near enough impossible. However, of the larger "camps" of denominations, the following at the very least do use catechisms:

- Roman Catholicism
- Reformed
- Lutheran
- Anglican

Roman Catholics typically subscribe to the Roman Catholic Catechism (http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_INDEX.HTM)

Reformed denominations (which may include and is not limited to: Reformed, Presbyterian, and Reformed/Calvinistic Baptist churches) often use one of or several of these:

- Heidelberg Catechism (http://www.heidelberg-catechism.com/en/)
- Westminster Shorter Catechism (http://www.westminsterconfession.org/confessional-standards/the-westminster-shorter-catechism.php)
- Westminster Longer Catechism (http://www.reformed.org/documents/larger1.html)

Lutheran denominations often use Luther's Catechism (http://bookofconcord.org/lc-1-intro.php)

Anglicans typically use the catechism in the Anglican Book of Common Prayer (http://anglicansonline.org/basics/catechism.html)

Comment: I found a newly printed ancelican catechism - put together in 2014.  I have yet to read it, but when I found it I wanted to add that information to my question here:  http://anglicanchurch.net/?/main/catechism